# Divisors $d | n$ such that $\mathrm{gcd}(d,n/d)$ is odd

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, terminology

In an application I'm looking at, the divisors $d | n$ of a number $n$ that satisfy $\mathrm{gcd}(d,n/d) = \mathrm{odd}$ seem to be important. This is a very weak version of "Hall divisors" which satisfy $\mathrm{gcd}(d,n/d) = 1.$

Is there a special name for this type of divisor? I would like to know what (asymptotic) properties of these divisors have been studied before.

Comment: I don't think it's uncommon or specific enough to have a name.  You are asking that $d$ is divisible by the highest power of 2 that divides $n$. ie.  $n = 2^km; m$ odd. and $d = 2^kg$.

Comment: @fleablood Those would be divisors such that $n/d$ is odd. I want divisors such that either $d$ or $n/d$ is odd (in other words, gcd($d,n/d$) is odd)

Comment: So?  Those are $\frac {n}{n/d} = d$ or $n/2^km$.  There are still too common, nonspecific and uninteresting to have names.

Comment: @fleablood I feel like you could say the same thing about unitary divisors, which are divisible by the highest power of $p$ that divides $n$ for any prime $p$ (if they are divisible by $p$ at all). If there isn't a name then that's fine. "Nonspecific" is a weird objection though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't mention this: let $$ n = 2^w m,  $$
where $m$ is odd. Take every divisor $t$ of $m,$ all the number pairs you want are
$$  2^w t \; \; , \; \; \;  \frac{m}{t}$$ 
as the product is $n$ and  the gcd is odd.

Comment: This is true although I don't know whether it implies the kind of asymptotic properties I am looking at (for example, "is $\limsup \frac{\sum_d d}{n \log(n)} = \mathrm{const}$ where $d$ runs through such divisors?")

Comment: @user149719 No, what if $n$ is prime...

Comment: That would be a trivial lower bound. I would rather get a nice upper bound. $\mathrm{const} \cdot n \log(n)$ works but I think it is too strong.

Comment: @user149719 see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/79927/which-n-maximize-gn-frac-sigmann-log-log-n